# Changing of emotions to deal with a given situation?

Tags: emotions

What do you call it when we change one feeling to another , more like channel it to something more applicable at that given at the time.
Something like channeling anger to determiniation?
Fear to anger?
Love to wariness.
Im not sure how to describe it to the the tiny detail.
But is something to the the point of changing one feeling to another that is not closely related.

Comment: You've used "channeling" in your examples, would this not work generally?

Comment: I was looking for a scientific term, and yes channeling doesnt work its something we do consciously and its not emotion to emotion, its more like emotion to execution

Comment: Mood adjustment?

Comment: "Harnessing" is a possible term.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a scientific concept, so there wouldn't be a scientific term for it. (Of course, I'm willing to be proven wrong, which will probably answer the question.) As mentioned on this page it's similar to the Freudian concept of "sublimation" but Freud's ideas are not part of mainstream psychology.

Comment: Hello, Garro. 'Controlling your emotions' obviously covers this and is idiomatic, but doesn't directly indicate forcibly swapping states.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to activities, 'sublimate' could be used in the context of emotion, converting the energy from a negative emotion into a positive one like in your first example. It perhaps wouldn't be as accurate going the other direction (positive to negative)..

Comment: Please add a suitable supporting definition (eg [M-W; 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sublimate)), [Collins; 3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sublimate)),  cemetery. I'd like to upvote this good answer.

Comment: *Sublimation* does have links to Freudian theory so if you're a psychologist you may have an opinion, but it's certainly a lot more specific than alternatives like *channeling*, *harnessing*, *redirecting*, *focusing*.